# getting nth node of a content type in drupal-7

Tags: php, drupal-7, paging

am unable to find any reference to retrieve a nth node of a custom content type in drupal.

e.g.

wish to show first three latest articles according to date.. then show article # 3,4,5 then 6,7,8th and so on.

kindly guide that how can this be achieved in drupal 7 and if it can be implemented better for paging purpose for a custom content type. (e.g. 5 latest articles in first page and then next five on page 2 ) ..

regards,
a.ali

Answer (score 0):

Views is the answer.
https://drupal.org/project/views

And a youtube tutorial on how to use Views module [Views Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3L9JLZOb_LQ)

Take the time to learn how to use the Views module , it'll be your beloved site building friend !!